How to install libldap-2.5-0 on Ubuntu 22.04
I tried installing SQL Server on my Ubuntu 22.04 and it failed. One of the errors was:
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: error while loading shared libraries: liblber-2.5.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mssql-server.service → /lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service.

I want to install libldap-2.5-0 package manually, using this source
I run
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libldap-2.5-0

that's the output I get:
sebastian@seb-linux-azure:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/mssql-server-2022 jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
sebastian@seb-linux-azure:~$ sudo apt-get install libldap-2.5-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libldap-2.5-0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libldap-2.5-0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libldap-2.5-0'

Is there a different way of installing that package?

Ubuntu 22.04 is codenamed jammy - based on your repositories, it looks like you are actually using 20.04 (focal) which afaik only has libldap-2.4-2

Good cath @steeldriver... Yeah, maybe @OP try apt-file find 'liblber-2.5.so.0' and see if something else is providing that library by any change (I'm not conviced though), you should probably reinstall the correct Ubuntu version for the guide that you're following.

I mean, I'm guessing you don't have the right version? What does lsb_release -a say?

oh. I spent hours on this and just realized I was on Ubuntu 20.04 while thinking I was on 22.04. Thanks for spotting this! Yeah lsb_release -a says 20.04
